# Using external program for indentation

Tags: vim, indentation

If using an external program for formatting, one can use something like `:%!program` to perform the formatting. Is it possible to use map this from the regular `=` and `==` sequences so that any indentation commands invoke the external program?

Comment: See `:help 'equalprg'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. `:help =` would have answered your question in no time:

```
={motion}       Filter {motion} lines through the external program
                        given with the 'equalprg' option.  When the 'equalprg'
                        option is empty (this is the default), use the
                        internal formatting function...
```

So, the answer is a simple

```
:set equalprg=program
```

You can put that in your `~/.vimrc`, or (if you only want this for certain buffers), use `:setlocal` (the option is either global or local, `:help 'equalprg'` tells you this) and put it in `~/.vim/after/{filetype}.vim`.